# Adding an overlay image on Google Street View

Tags: google-maps, overlay, google-street-view

I am trying to display an overlay image within street view.
I used the code available on google documentation regarding Custom Overlays:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays

It says that if I want to show my overlay within Street View I have to pass a panorama instead of a map, this is what I do:

```
panorama = map.getStreetView();
panorama.setPosition(astorPlace);
panorama.setPov({
  heading: 120,
  zoom:1,
  pitch:0}
);


var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(40.725882, -74.000986);
var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(40.734886, -73.980990);
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);

var srcImage = 'overlay.jpeg';
overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, panorama);
```

Nothing shows up (if I pass "map" instead of "panorama" to USGOverlay everything's fine).
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: did you ever figure it out? I'm trying to do similar now.